# In Ansible, how do I store passed in json in a file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.6.3

I wrote an Ansible role to create secrets in AWS secret manger, and I want to be able to call it like this

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," secretsmanager.yml -e command=update -e service_name=test-svc -e text_box='{"secret":"value"}'
```

I first copy the values of the passed-in json to

```
/tmp/{{ service_name }}.json
```

so in this example the file is

```
/tmp/test-svc.json
```

Here's the task that copies it

```
- name: Setup up dest file
  set_fact:
    secret: "{{ service_name }}"
    dst_file: "/tmp/{{ service_name }}.json"

- name: "Copy {{ text_box }} to {{ dst_file }}"
  shell: |
     echo {{ text_box }} > {{ dst_file }}
```

However, when I look at /tmp/test-svc.json it looks like

```
$ cat /tmp/test-svc.json 
{secret:value}
```

How can I do this so the json file is correct, that is?

```
{"secret":"value"}
```

Since this will be used by my users, I want them to be able to write the json normally, that is without incorporating escape characters in the json itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two methods to do this:

1) Use Jinja2 filter to force the output to JSON

```
- name: "Copy {{ text_box }} to {{ dst_file }}"
  shell: |
    echo {{ text_box | to_json }} > {{ dst_file }}
```

2) Use the Ansible `copy` module. I would argue this is better because it gives you more control over the file and automatically does the right thing in this case.

```
- copy:
    dest: "{{ dst_file }}"
    content: "{{ text_box }}"
```

As an aside, if you haven't already, could be worth having a read of the docs for [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html). Dependent on your environment, passing your secrets over the command line as arguments is not massively secure. Depending on your use case, you might find storing the secrets in Ansible Vault adds an additional layer of protection.